# How to fetch one row and display it on textbox and increment it automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

i wrote this python 3 program, i want to for each row in field Esperanto, get it's corresponding row in the other field in database named English. for example: when i click on row 1 in listbox, i want the text of the row 1 in English field of my db to be displayed on the textbox. now it fetches all the rows and it's a disaster, how can i do that? thanks.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3
    #GeologyDict by Ali M
    import sqlite3 as sqlite
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import Text
    from tkinter import Entry
    from tkinter import Scrollbar
    from tkinter import ttk

    #GUI Widgets


    class EsperantoDict:
    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title("EsperantoDict")
        master.resizable(False, False)
        master.configure(background='#EAFFCD')

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background='#EAFFCD')
        self.style.configure("TButton", background='#EAFFCD')
        self.style.configure("TLabel", background='#EAFFCD')

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master, relief=tk.FLAT)
        self.frame_header.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.logo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\EsperantoDict\eo.png')
        self.small_logo = self.logo.subsample(10, 10)

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, image=self.small_logo).grid(row=0, column=0, stick="ne", padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=2)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text='EsperantoDict', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold')).grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        self.entry_search = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content)
        self.entry_search.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry_search.insert(tk.END, "Type to Search")
        self.entry_search.bind('<Button-1>', self.entry_delete)

        self.button_search = ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text="Search")
        self.aks = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\EsperantoDict\search.png')
        self.small_aks = self.aks.subsample(3, 3)
        self.button_search.config(image=self.small_aks, compound=tk.LEFT)
        self.button_search.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.frame_content, height=28)
        self.listbox.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_content, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.enter_meaning)

        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.frame_content, width=60, height=27)
        self.textbox.grid(row=1, column=2)

    # SQLite
        self.db = sqlite.connect(r'C:\EsperantoDict\test.db')
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('SELECT Esperanto FROM Words')
        for row in self.cur:
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, row)
    # SQLite

    def enter_meaning(self, tag):
        if self.listbox.curselection():
            results = self.cur.execute("SELECT English FROM Words")
            for row in results:
                self.textbox.insert(tk.END, row)


    def entry_delete(self, tag):
        self.entry_search.delete(0, tk.END)
        return None


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    esperantodict = EsperantoDict(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()

#db table name: Words
##db first field name: Esperanto
##db second field name: English
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to drop all the `tkinter` complexity for this problem and set up a small test-case focused only on sqlite3. Your query has no restrictions at all, so it's clear that you'd pull the whole database.

Comment: oh ok. so how can i restrict it and fetch rows with auto increment? please give code i'm a beginner. thanks.

Comment: This is not just a place that gives code. I'm happy to try direct you where you should be looking but it doesn't mean I, or anyone else, will write it for you. I suggest you look at some sqlite tutorials and learn about parameterized queries. A couple of hours of that and you'll know how to fix it yourself with ease. You'll need to learn about `WHERE`.

Comment: i know about where command, but i couldn't figure out how to use it. I've read tutorials, still no luck. i used "SELECT English FROM Words WHERE ROWID=1" instead of that 1 what should i put in there to increment it automatically?

Comment: I don't see exactly where the counter is coming from (the thing being incremented) `self.cur.execute("""SELECT English FROM Words WHERE ROWID=?""", (counter,))`

Comment: Oh, maybe i should change this line: self.textbox.insert(tk.END, row). Because tk.END writes all the querry results in textbox, but i want one of them to appear on selection of each row.